# I would like to develop a jekyll gem plugin, but I don't know how to start

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I don't find tutorials to develop and publish jekyll plugins or to extend jekyll functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Jekyll's documentation on how to get started with Jekyll plugins https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: I used the jekyll's documentation + https://github.com/field-theory/jekyll-category-pages as example + https://rubygems.org/ to understand what are gems + ruby documentation and I was able to build my own plugin. thanks